# If string contains number, save number in variable?

Tags: php

So heres what i have. I have an array of `$_POST` elements and some end with a number, some do not. So whatI have already is:

```
foreach ($_POST as $field_name => $value){ }
```

What id like to do it put an if statement within the foreach, and say 'if $field_name contains a number, save that number in a variable $num'. And then foreach $field_name that contains that same $num, do this...

Im pretty clear on the concept, but not the actual code. The first step would be to determine if the the field contains a digit 1-9 within it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Soon (1-2 mins) some people will reply giving you the correct answer. In the meanwhile you can look `preg_match` in the PHP documentation. Byes!

Comment: Why not simply use `intval()` if the digit can't be zero? http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_match`!

```
if( preg_match('/\d+/', $field_name, $matches) ) {
    $num = $matches[0];
    // Do other stuff here
}
```

(Edit: simplified)

Comment: If the number is at the end of the field name, this would be less greedy:
`/(\d+)$/`

Comment: you're missing a closing bracket at the end of the if line.

Comment: Wow, weird that nobody caught that for 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

Better do it without regular expression its much faster!!

```
if (strcspn($_Post[$i], '0123456789') != strlen($_Post[$i])){}
```

no need to start the regularexpression engine...

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Use a RegEx.

Comment: benchmark it! starting the regex engine takes time. why not do it faster? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php#94110

Comment: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."
- Brian Kernighan

Comment: especially in this case... it is a very simple pattern that can be replaced by an existing php function. and we are looping i times so regex engine will start i times too... I would use strcspn ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
preg_match_all('/[1-9]/', $field_name, $matches);
```

$matches should contain now all number occurencies stored in array. Proccess it how you prefer :D

Comment: if you take all you should use $matches[0] to get your result.